# Change color on button toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code which was supposed to toggle color between transparent and white on button click. [This](https://codepen.io/sahil-sharma/pen/WavwVK) is the codepen link.

The `div` I want the color changed has the class `points`

```
<div class="points">100 points</div>
```

But running this javascript code returns an error

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('points').style.color = color;
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined

Answer (score -1):

> The getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of all
>   elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList
>   object.

Use the following code to achieve what you want -

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("points");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.color = color;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `document.getElementsByClassName()` Returns an array of controls, and in your code, there is not any specific index position to set the style for that particular element or control.

The modified working code as:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('points')[0].style.color = 'red';

console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('points'));
```

```html
<div class="points">100 points</div>
```